# Image Inserted as plane wont display- is purple

Tags: image

Ive been working over an image inserted as a plane, and I recently closed blender for the first time in a while. Upon reopening, the image I had inserted is..gone! and purple!
[image]

I found a post on another forum that mentioned this could be caused by frames, but I am unsure of how to remedy that.

Thanks!

Comment: Probably Blender can't find the image where it was previously, go into File > External Data > Find Missing File and find the file. If you want to save it within the blend file: File > External Data > Pack All Into .blend

Comment: If nothing works you can just reinsert the image as a plane